# Is there any equivalent of function myfunction(x, y) in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

In JavaScript, we have functions with arguments like this:

```
function myFunction(a, b) {
return a * b;
}
```

I'm learning jQuery and want to know if we have something equivalent in jQuery or we just use this same syntax in jQuery as well?

Comment: Most of the use of jquery is used to manipulate dom, and it also has its own [utility functions](https://api.jquery.com/category/utilities/). Actually, in some cases you can use native js directly.

Answer (score 0):

We use this syntax in jQuery as well.  We use same syntax for function . Jquery is a library that provide you function or expression that help you to do work much faster and gives backward compatibilaty  . Some time you should use plain JavaScript . For example I do not use jQuery for ajax because it is over killing as per my experience and as I know .

Comment: Unless you use fetch, the jQuery ajax is great if you already are using jQuery. Xmlhttprequest is a mess compared to the before mentioned methods

Answer (score 0):

```js
var myFunction = function (a, b) {
    return a * b;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.